# Derivative of $f = {\rm tr} \left[ U^T \; {\rm unvec} \left( B \ {\rm vec}(X) \right) \right]$ w.r.t. $X$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

Let a block diagonal matrix reads $$B := {\rm blkdiag}\left(A_1, \cdots, A_i, \cdots, A_N \right) \ \in \mathbb{R}^{MN \times KN} \ ,$$ where $A_i \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times K}$.

How to take the derivative of $f = {\rm tr} \left[ U^T \;  {\rm unvec} \left(  B \ {\rm vec}(X) \right) \right]$, where $U \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times N}$ and $X \in \mathbb{R}^{K \times N}$ w.r.t. $X$?

Comment: Just clarification. does "unvec" operation creates matrix, that is reverse operation of a "vec"?

Comment: @user550103. yes, that's correct.

Comment: What hapened when you evaluated $$f(X+H)-f(X)$$ with $H$ small?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the vectors
$$\eqalign{
 x &= {\rm vec}(X) \cr
 u &= {\rm vec}(U) \cr
}$$
Write your function in terms of the vectors. Then find the differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
 f &= u^TBx = (B^Tu)^Tx \cr
df &= (B^Tu)^T\,dx \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= B^Tu \cr
}$$
Now de-vectorize this to obtain a matrix result.
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} &= {\rm unvec}(B^Tu) \cr
}$$